# Blog Template isn't overridden

Tags: silverstripe

I have to change the templates of the blogging module of SilverStripe.

I can do this in the blog/templates directory, but when I want to update this module my changes are lost.

I read about template overriding here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/theme-development.

The page says that by creating the file `BlogHolder.ss` in the directory `\mysite\templates\Layout` should override the template in the blog module. This isn't working. However a CSS works and is overridden.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Placing the file in `\mysite\templates\Layout` should work. Make sure you call `?flush=all`

Answer (score 3):

You should put your theme into a separate directory from your project. The only templates you should really put into your project folder are default templates that can be overwritten by a theme.

The order in which SilverStripe looks for templates is:

- Subtheme
- Theme
- Module Folder (blog)
- Project Folder (mysite)

Your BlogHolder.ss file should be placed in /themes/*mytheme*/templates/Layout/BlogHolder.ss